# Setting ForeignKey property with Fluent api and EntityBuilder<T> in c#

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have the following the poco class;

```
public class Trader : AuditableEntity
{
    public int AccountManagerId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser AccountManager { get; set; }
}
```

Where `AccountManagerId` is the foreign key to `AccountManager`.

When I then setup the data in EntityFrameworkCore is use the `EntityTypeBuilder<T>` to configure.

```
public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Trader> entity)
{
    entity.HasKey(x => x.Id);
    ...
```

How using Fluent API can I state that `AccountManager.HasForeignKey(AccountManagerId)` please as I cannot see how to do this?

`ApplicationUser` has no reference to Trader, this is a one way relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1-N relation:

```
entity.HasOne(x => x.AccountManager).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.AccountManagerId);
```

For 1-1 relation:

```
entity.HasOne(x => x.AccountManager).WithOne().HasForignKey<Trader>(x => x.AccountManagerId);
```